# Can photons be produced by making oscillations in the electromagnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, quantum-electrodynamics

Oscillating an object in water creates waves in it. Oscillating an object in air can creates sound waves. Likewise by making something (something which interacts with the field) oscillate in the electromagnetic field can electromagnetic waves be produced?

Answer (score 4):

Yes. That's basically the *only* way that electromagnetic waves can be produced. Charged particles interact with the electromagnetic field, and accelerating charges produces electromagnetic waves.

Strictly speaking, electromagnetic radiation can be produced whenever a charge changes state. Classically, this only corresponds to true physical acceleration, but when quantum mechanics enters the picture it also includes annihilation of charges and such.

Comment: Well is there any constraint that oscillations with only certain amplitude is required?

Comment: have a look http://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/whyantennasradiate.php

Comment: @Saptarshisarma Not really. Different amplitudes will change the electromagnetic wave you get, but any oscillation of a charge will give you electromagnetic waves

Comment: Then just charging an object and moving it would do the job??

Comment: @Saptarshisarma Yep

Comment: Can light also be produced?

Comment: @Saptarshisarma Light is just a type of electromagnetic wave, so yes. Practically speaking this is quite difficult, though, because visible light has an extremely high frequency. So you have to accelerate a charge *very* fast to produce visible light.

Comment: EM waves are produced in an LED without any charged particles being substantially accelerated.

Comment: @Chris Not a physicist, but I feel like I remember learning in undergrad that light can also be produced by collision/annihilation of a positron and an electron. Is this correct?

Comment: @ThePhoton I wouldn't really say that hole recombination involves no acceleration- the electron suddenly jumps from a high energy state to a low energy state.

Comment: @DavidReed Yes. That is an effect in QFT that is analogous to classical acceleration. In one formalism of QFT, an electron and a positron annihilating is equivalent to an electron being accelerated to a state that moves backwards in time.

Comment: @Chris, but that transition involves only a very slight change in momentum.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is exactly what happens when a radio antenna is used for transmission. Electrons moving along the antenna's wires accellerate back and forth, and this produces electromagnetic waves.

The photon energy at radio frequencies is quite small, so it is difficult to measure quantum phenomena at these frequencies. However that does not mean the wave is not quantized.